# R: using grep-like function to extract cerain bits of a table

Tags: r

Thanks to all who replied. Let me re-edit my previous post to make explicit what I would need. I do have an input data structured like this:
[image: input data]
The first column has a sample name, the second and third are description of an event and the last column has a set of genes spaced by " ". This is, off course, a screenshot from XLS, but I have no problem importing them to R.

I would like to create a loop in R that goes through every row and every column in the table and searches for gene names that would be supplied as a vector. (For ex: genes <- c("APC", "TP53")). If it finds the match, then it would copy the line to the new matrix. However, I do want to know which gene from the vector it found, and therefore all remaining ones from D column have to be omitted.

I should be able to create the loop, but failed doing the grep function and not really sure how to omit the remaining genes from the row.

The ideal output should look like this:

> Papillary.01.2007.02142C LOH 2 BOLA1

Thanks much for your thoughts.

Comment: Given that the space-delimited file contains changing numbers of genes per line, I would be tempted to read the whole line with `readLines`, then use `grep` to identify the lines matching your gene list and convert the matching lines into a suitable format afterwards...

Comment: That might work, but I would like to get rid of all genes not matching in the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
# define data, could be read from file with dat <- read.table(file, sep="\t")
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(
    c("Papillary.01.2007.02142C", "LOH", "2", "SNX27 RPD2 BOLA1",
    "Papillary.01.2007.02142C", "LOH", "2", "APC MOGS STAMBP",
    "Papillary.01.2007.02142C", "LOH", "2", "TGFBR2",
    "Papillary.01.2007.02142C", "LOH", "2", "TP52 CNTN5 EV12A",
    "Papillary.01.2007.02142C", "LOH", "2", "APC TRIM37 PRR11 FAM33A"),
    ncol=4, byrow=T
))
# gene vector
vec <- c("APC", "TP53", "TP52")
# apply function over the gene vector, to return a data frame with 
# matching rows. Also include column containing query gene
out <- lapply(vec, function(gene) {
    df <- dat[grep(gene, dat[, 4]), ]
    df$match <- rep(gene, nrow(df))
    df
})
# combine results and subset to get desired output
out <- do.call(rbind, out)
out[, c(1:3, 5)]
```

Output:

```
                        V1  V2 V3 match
2 Papillary.01.2007.02142C LOH  2   APC
5 Papillary.01.2007.02142C LOH  2   APC
4 Papillary.01.2007.02142C LOH  2  TP52
```

Note that rows will be repeated in the output if two different genes match the same row...

Comment: Almost there. True, I am getting the list of genes and the list of samples, but the CN state and LOH is missing. I would need something like this APC Sample1 2 LOH... and then in the next line APC Sample 4 4 Gain.

Comment: IMO it would be useful if you could give a clearer reproducible example.

Comment: Hope it's now clear. Respectively, would it help, if I change the spacing between the genes to \t?

Comment: I would keep spacing between genes to " " and spacing between the four columns to "\t". I think this is the default when you copy/paste out of excel. Assuming you do this, you can just read the file with read.table, using "\t" as a separator. I will/have edited my answer to reflect this assumption